# All coaches of English football team

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I try to query Wikidata for all coaches of English Football Team

```
SELECT ?team ?coachLabel  
WHERE {
         ?team wdt:P31 wd:Q47762.  
         ?team p:P286 ?statement.  
         ?statement ps:P286 ?coach.
         SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".}

      }
```

But my query give me only last coach.
What's wrong?

Comment: There is a P286 property in England National Football Team [link]https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q47762

Comment: You need just `wd:Q47762 p:P286/ps:P286 ?coach.`. You (and I) were confused by some kind of punning: `wd:Q47762` is also a class, not only individual on Wikidata: `wd:Q47762 ^wdt:P31 wd:Q22002163` holds.

Comment: Thx. It really helps.
SELECT ?coach ?coachLabel
WHERE {
  wd:Q47762 p:P286 ?team.
  ?team ps:P286 ?coach.  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".}
}